# Seeking Career/Learning Guidance in ML/AI: Navigating Job Search and looking for an area to Specialise

Tags: job-search, career-development, career-switch, skills, europe

I wanted to for advice as I started looking for jobs and realised I need a concrete plan about what I want to do so I wish you could help me a bit. I am from the EU. I started applying to around 30-40 companies but got only 1 interview for ML still in progress. I have like 5 months or more to find a job. For now, I looked in Belgium but tbh I dont want to stay here for long(weather, taxes). I plan to apply for jobs in Germany, the Netherlands, Poland(my origin country) and Switzerland(I love mountains and nature but never was there). I look for the most growth opportunities and life quality.

I feel like I need to decide what type of specialization I want to have in like 5 years. And reevaluate my learning priorities to get good starting jobs to provide more value to my profile.

I also look for nice resources to track what happening in the field or what professional ML code should look like.

Intro:

I was a Robotic/engineer for 2 years after my BSc, but I find ML/programming very cool. I wanted to know how the math and algorithms predict all of these things. I started learning myself and applied for an MSc. I got an MSc in CS.

Now I am finishing it and got a good job in Data science that was well paid but I decided to not follow it as there was no ML. I have a part-time job in the AI lab at my uni for now.

I also got a Ph.D. offer in the lab where I can do ML but I feel like it's in a domain I am not a fan of and it's quite a long commitment as I worked 2 years between BSc and MSc.

Skills:

- Mainly programming in Python got courses in Scala(I like it but need to practice more) and Java(was quite okay with it but not used a lot). Also know a bit: SQL, MATLAB, C#, C++, HTML, CSS
- I used PyTorch, SciPy, and Keras. I feel confident in SciPy I practice my pytorch to implement models as I could have more understanding regarding it. Used gymnasium for Reinforcement Learning Course. I use and for visualisation and hyperoptimization as I find it nice for the thesis and as a skill to learn.
- Maybe I am lacking here I know map reduction but I dont use Hadoop, Docker, or BiqQUery like once for a project

What I like/feel like focusing on:

- enjoyed the Reinforcement Learning Course and Scala but I dont have much experience here. We do a lot of medical-related ML projects also which feels like contributing. I like Robotics also. Do also VQA which was cool (NLP part especially).
- I look for clean ML jobs like 80% ml 20 % research, no SQL queries(could make it a bit), making SMTH useful, easily used, small dashboard draft of what it feels like. I also have no problem with cleaning and understanding data.
- read a bit about SAP in ML but do not understand what this type of work looks like.

I only find a few jobs related to this and they require like 2-3 years at least of experience or PhD/research experience.

My plan:

- Working on this part-time job and focusing on a Thesis related to Deep Learning that should be published to get some bonus points later for job hunting.
- In my free time I focus on strong Python skills, coding exercises on Exercism(Python, really rarely Scala), and doing Coursera Machine Learning Specialization and Deep Learning | Coursera when noting and understanding all things and making some flashcards second brain in obsidian for ML practices and so on. Further, I do a bit https://www.coursera.org/learn/deep-neural-networks-with-pytorch/home/welcome but I decided to stop it and do last to get strong fundamentals in knowing all machine learning models first.
- All of this is to prepare me to recreate papers from high-impact machine learning journals and document them in the form of video to attach them to my future CV.  I also like the idea of doing projects and documenting them for fun but I dont find time to do that.

My weakness:

- I dont use at all AWS, SPARK, Azure, Snowflake, and Hadoop
- I forget some ML things from courses and feel like my math understanding could be better, hence why I focus on these skills.
- improving my Pytorch skills
- no project on GitHub as I picked courses to have projects everywhere for hands-on experience but I can't publish them, maybe an interview with HR but could be a legal issue. Dont have much time now to do some just for this purpose.
- my code could be better which is why I took a Software Architecture course in Scala, in my uni they are always happy with my code but in the industry, it is probably not acceptable.

Quite a long post I tried to make it as concise and understandable as possible.

If you have any advice regarding anything above I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: "What should I study/which career should I pursue" is one of the questions we really can't answer for you. "What are good study materials for AI" is better asked in an AI-related discussion since it's specific to that one niche rather than being about the basics of employment.... but I suspect that even there you're going to get suggestions to narrow your focus.

Comment: (Nitpick: concise means compact and trimmed to essential.  And making it concise -would- make people more willing to read through it and respond. When you ask elsewhere, focus on one specific answerable question at a time, and consider leaving out anything not directly needed to answer that question.)